# How to pass email-address to contact form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

How can i pass a certain value (email-adress) from a customer-information page (where i see all the customers information) to an "overall" contact-form, which is reachable under 'myhost.com/contact'.

I want something like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Send email to customer', contact_path %>
```

with the specific email-adress to be passed.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the email address as a parameter as shown in the following pseudo-code:

```
<%= link_to "Send Email to Customer", contact_path(:email_address => customer.email) %>
```

Where customer is the customer object you want to email.

You could also send the customer id and use the id to get the customer's email in the contact page.

```
<%= link_to "Send Email to Customer", contact_path(:customer => customer.id) %>
```

Comment: So ':email_address' is the variable i can then use in the form?

Comment: It would be params[:email_address] in the params hash.

Comment: See the edit above. Sorry for the confusion. I just tested the way above, and it works.

Comment: No confusion :) just want to make shure I understand you right!